Сгенерировать ссылку на телеграм-web-app которая стразу предложит открыть приложение
Я хочу отправить пользователю ссылку на свое мини-приложение (встроенное в телеграмм), я отправляю такую ссылку https://t.me/myappbot?startapp=id
но при этом он просто переходит в чат с ботом.
а хотелось бы чтобы ссылка превращалась в такой вот вид

буду благодарен за полезную информацию!

Вы используете ссылку формата https://t.me/myappbot?startapp=id. Измените её, следуя формату https://t.me/myappbot/start?startapp=id
